# Absolute positioned element still needs to set height for following content

Tags: html, css

I am challenged by a layout where the top header content needs to have a menu that opens up dynamically and floats above all the other content.  This leads me to think it has to be absolute positioned.  This is hard to explain so I created a fiddle that looks like this :

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/4WzA8/

The section CONTENT 3 is hidden by default and in this example visibility is toggled by clicking on CONTENT 2 list.  I need it to overlay the rest of the content, including 4.  The problem is the main content wrapper does not read the height of this absolute positioned element.  I tried to apply the clearfix as described [here](http://www.css-101.org/articles/clearfix/latest-new-clearfix-so-far.php).

```
header:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
    clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `position: absolute;` the elements is removed from document normal flow and the flow of the document goes behind the absolute positioned element.

That's not a clearing fix issue. and it won't be resolved that way.

You need to add a propery value of `margin-top` to the `wrapper` to push it down. But in this case the header should have an explicit height.

Or just don't position the header absolutely. and use `overflow: hidden;` for clearing fix.

Also this method would be appropriate to clearing the floats:

```css
.clearfix:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
    clear:both;
}

.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1; /*  Trigger hasLayout in IE 6/7 */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I understand it removes it from the flow and that is what I need to happen, for CONTENT 3, in my example.  I wish I could just add `margin-top` as that would make this easy but the other divs need to be able to change in height.  I am not sure what you mean using `overflow: hidden`.  Would you mind tweaking my fiddle so I can see what you are talking about?

Comment: @Zac the point is only `#content3` should be positioned absolutely. not the entire header, you need to position the list as `relative` and the overlay menu `absolute`: http://jsfiddle.net/4WzA8/1/

Comment: Thanks, that works but it looks like you edited the markup more than I am able.  The overlay menu can not be a sibling list element as you have it but is in a separate div, actually my example is wrong in that the overly should have another div element between it and the nav.  Anyways I appreciate your help, I really want to avoid having to set any fixed pixel height for the absolute positioned element but I do not see any way around it.

Comment: @Zac I assumed that the overlay menu is unique for each navigation link. If so, you need to place the menu inside each `<li>` element. Else, the menu should be somewhere in which you can handle the position of the menu when it's displayed. As you may know, setting `position: relative` to the *parent* makes the parent to be a reference point for the `absolute` positioned elements. Hence the absolute element (the overlay menu) should be placed in proper place.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  After some struggle I finally figured out what was happening.  My `position:relative` parent was being ignored until I added `float: left` to it, until I did that it was like positioning to `body`.   Now the child `absolute` elements are positioned how I would expect.